# Bootstrap / Business Catalyst Broken menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav, business-catalyst

Can someone please explain to me why the menu for this url works: 
http://savethecute.businesscatalyst.com/pictures
and this one doesn't 
http://savethecute.businesscatalyst.com/pictures/
I have compared the source code and they are identical.  A solution would be even better, but I don't even know where to start since I don't understand why there is a difference.

I am using the latest version of bootstrap inside business catalyst and am still very early in the design process.

Any clarification is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap style and script links that you've added use relative url's, they don't start with for example a `http://`. This makes your browser use the current url as a starting point when looking for the resource.

For example in the `head` you use

```
<link href="_assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to refer to Bootstrap's css. For the url without the slash, http://savethecute.businesscatalyst.com/pictures, this becomes:

```
<link href="http://savethecute.businesscatalyst.com/_assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

which can be found by the browser. However the url including the slash becomes:

```
<link href="http://savethecute.businesscatalyst.com/pictures/_assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and at that location you don't serve Bootstrap's css.

I think you have three options to solve this:

1. Make the url including the slash redirect to the one without the slash
2. Add a `base` tag to the `head` of your html. This makes every relative url become relative to the base url. In your case add `<base href="http://savethecute.businesscatalyst.com/">`
3. Serve Bootstrap from a CDN (as you already do for Font Awesome). See http://www.bootstrapcdn.com for instructions

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer and tried to explain it a little better.